# How to use C++ linked list in Ros node?

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

to use the linked list in a Cpp code we use include .. but it doesn't work for a ROS node,SO
how can I use it in a ROS node??!!

I assume that the problem that cmakelists should has something to declare the C++ standard libraries
my catkin_make output:

```
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp: In constructor ‘Graph::Graph(int)’:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:25:12: error: expected type-specifier before ‘list’
  adj = new list<int>[V];
            ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:25:12: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘list’
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:26:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  tree = int[V][V];
         ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:26:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp: In member function ‘void Graph::GridToGraph(int, int)’:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:54:6: error: ‘g’ was not declared in this scope
      g.addEdge(grid[k][j], grid[k + 1][j]);
      ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:61:5: error: ‘g’ was not declared in this scope
     g.addEdge(grid[k][j], grid[k][j + 1]);
     ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:66:5: error: ‘g’ was not declared in this scope
     g.addEdge(grid[k][j], grid[k][j + 1]);
     ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp: In member function ‘void Graph::prim_st()’:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:95:5: error: ‘list’ was not declared in this scope
     list<int>::iterator i;
     ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:95:5: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:63:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/forwards.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:438:11: note:   ‘std::list’
     class list : protected _List_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/include_preprocessed.hpp:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/list.hpp:46,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/policy.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/list.hpp:22:8: note:   ‘boost::mpl::list’
 struct list;
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:170:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/transport_hints.h:34,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/subscribe_options.h:33,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:41,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/container/container_fwd.hpp:68:7: note:   ‘boost::container::list’
 class list;
       ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:95:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     list<int>::iterator i;
          ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:95:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:10: error: name lookup of ‘i’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping [-fpermissive]
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
          ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:10: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:12: error: cannot convert ‘std::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}’ to ‘int’ in assignment
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
            ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:32: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘std::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}’)
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:32: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iterator:66:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/detail/iterator.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/include/boost/array.hpp:48,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message.h:38,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h:33,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stream_iterator.h:137:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Dist> bool std::operator!=(const std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>&, const std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>&)
     operator!=(const istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stream_iterator.h:137:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:63:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/forwards.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1638:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const list<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const list<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1638:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:63:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/forwards.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:282:5: note: template<class _Val> bool std::operator!=(const std::_List_iterator<_Tp>&, const std::_List_const_iterator<_Val>&)
     operator!=(const _List_iterator<_Val>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:282:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::_List_iterator<_Tp>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/set:62:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/forwards.h:34,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_multiset.h:763:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_multiset.h:763:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/set:61:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/forwards.h:34,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:778:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:778:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:62:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:42,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:40,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_multimap.h:888:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_multimap.h:888:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:42,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:40,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:986:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:986:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:60:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:42,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:40,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:927:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:927:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:60:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:42,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:40,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:316:5: note: template<class _Val> bool std::operator!=(const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>&, const std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Val>&)
     operator!=(const _Rb_tree_iterator<_Val>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:316:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/format.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:1428:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:1428:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/complex.hpp:21:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/complex:484:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator!=(const _Tp&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
     operator!=(const _Tp& __x, const complex<_Tp>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/complex:484:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   ‘std::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::complex<_Tp>’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/complex.hpp:21:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/complex:479:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator!=(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const _Tp&)
     operator!=(const complex<_Tp>& __x, const _Tp& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/complex:479:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::complex<_Tp>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/complex.hpp:21:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/complex:474:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator!=(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
     operator!=(const complex<_Tp>& __x, const complex<_Tp>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/complex:474:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::complex<_Tp>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:54,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:210:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator!=(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)
     operator!=(const istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>& __a,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:210:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/platform.h:55,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:53,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2556:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
     operator!=(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2556:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/platform.h:55,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:53,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2544:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const _CharT* __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2544:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/platform.h:55,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:53,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2532:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2532:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:41:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/platform.h:55,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:53,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:143:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator!=(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_CharT>&)
     operator!=(const allocator<_Tp>&, const allocator<_Tp>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:143:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::allocator<_CharT>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:41:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/platform.h:55,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:53,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:138:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator!=(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)
     operator!=(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:138:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::allocator<_CharT>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:40,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/platform.h:55,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:53,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/postypes.h:221:5: note: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator!=(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
     operator!=(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/postypes.h:221:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::fpos<_StateT>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:40,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/platform.h:55,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:53,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:353:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator!=(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:353:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:40,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/platform.h:55,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:53,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:303:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator!=(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:303:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:40,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/platform.h:55,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:53,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:227:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator!=(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator!=(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:227:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:96:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’ and ‘int’
     for (i = adj[j].begin(); i != adj[j].end(); ++i)
                                              ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:99:20: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
      if (selected[*i] == true)
                    ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:105:13: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
        y = *i;
             ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:107:17: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
        tree[x][0] = x;
                 ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:108:17: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
        tree[x][1] = y;
                 ^
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp: At global scope:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:116:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
make[2]: *** [moon/CMakeFiles/SpanningTree.dir/src/SpanningTree.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [moon/CMakeFiles/SpanningTree.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232096/how-to-use-c++-linked-list-in-ros-node??/) by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error is:

```
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/moon/src/SpanningTree.cpp:25:12: error: expected type-specifier before ‘list’ adj = new list<int>[V];
```

The types in the C++ standard library are provided in the `std` namespace.

It looks like either you forgot to prefix your use of `list` with the `std::` namespace, or you forgot to add `using namespace std;` to the top of your cpp file.

I ***strongly*** prefer and recommend using the `std::` prefix. The `using namespace ...;` clause can cause name collisions and other surprises. (most C++ books have an opinion on this, too).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on 2016-04-18**:
thanks that work ;)